# Microsoft Owin breaking VS Locally

Tags: .net, iis, visual-studio-2017, owin

I've been having an issue with Microsoft Visual Studio 2017 (we are using asp.net framework) that none of my team seems to get. It happens randomly and the only solution I've found in the past was to reformat my hard drive. Basically, the project starts to just give me this error:

```
System.IO.FileLoadException: 'Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Owin, Version=2.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)'
```

I don't really have a rhyme or reason why it is caused and none of the backend developers at my work understand why it is happening. I know it pertains to IIS and suspect it is an issue with my locally cached files since no one else in the project is getting the issue.

I've read through a lot of search results on google, most solutions are 5 or 6 years old and don't seem to be what I need. If anyone has any advice or can help me further debug this issue I'd greatly appreciate it. I really don't feel like reformating my hard drive everytime this issue pops up :'(

Thanks

Comment: re-add the NuGet references to the project and rebuild the solution.

Comment: I've tried this before, I don't think the actual issue in the project code but rather in VS itself. Is there a chance I could have some bad cache somewhere that would cause this issue?

Comment: in VS options there is an option to clean NuGet cache. if you use packages.config, delete the files/folders under packages in your solution folder